# how to have the oracle sql results in a numeric order

Tags: oracle, sql-order-by, natural-sort

This is what my Oracle SQL command looks like:

```
select domain 
from table1 
order by 1 desc
```

and here is the actual order of the returned data:

```
us9.aaa.com
us8.aaa.com
us10.aaa.com 
us1.aaa.com
```

My question is, how can I make the data returned be in an order like this?

```
us10.aaa.com
us9.aaa.com
us8.aaa.com
us1.aaa.com
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way using regexp_replace().  It does not care how many non-numeric characters are before the numeric portion of the domain name that you want to sort on (nor does it care how large the numeric portion is):

```
SQL> with table1(domain) as (
     select 'us9.aaa.com' from dual
     union
     select 'us8.aaa.com' from dual
     union
     select 'us10.aaa.com' from dual
     union
     select 'us1.aaa.com' from dual
   )
   select domain
   from table1
   order by to_number(regexp_replace(domain, '^\D+(\d+)\..*', '\1')) desc;

DOMAIN
------------
us10.aaa.com
us9.aaa.com
us8.aaa.com
us1.aaa.com

SQL>
```

The regex can be read as "Look for one or more non-digit characters at the start of the string, followed by a remembered group of one or more digits, followed by a literal period, followed by any number of any characters (until the end of the string is implied)".  The '\1' means return the 1st remembered group which is the number, which is converted to a number which is what the ORDER BY works on.

Answer (score 1):

Mixing alphas and numerics into ordering is difficult, however if the format is fixed it is doable by breaking out the componenets. In your case you could, for example:

```
with dat as (select 'us9.aaa.com' addr from dual union all
    select 'us8.aaa.com' addr from dual union all
    select 'us10.aaa.com' addr from dual union all
    select 'us1.aaa.com' addr from dual)
select addr from dat
order by to_number(substr(addr,3,instr(addr,'.')-3)) desc
```

which returns:

```
ADDR           
"us10.aaa.com" 
"us9.aaa.com"  
"us8.aaa.com"  
"us1.aaa.com"
```